# JSON Parsing in Android - Read 4 sections at the same time?

Tags: android, json

I'm getting some bus infos from a json source but the problem is that i couldn't read the subinfos from some sections.

JSON file is like:

```
{
 "1.webAccessCheck":0.000010013580322266,
 "5.timeDiff":0.000016927719116211,
 "val":"postVal",
 "2.saveipDiff":0.08434796333313,
 "func":"rd",
 "routeCoorInfo":[
      "41502",
      "1",
      "2013/09/15 05:06:22",
      "004",
      "59"
 ],
 "servicetimediff":3197,
 "busStopInfo":{
      "SeqNo":[
           "1",
           "2",
           "3",
           "4",
           "5",
           "6",
           "7",
           "8",
           "9",
           "10"
      ],
      "Lat":[
           "40.799931",
           "40.801025",
           "40.801291",
           "40.802394",
           "40.804359",
           "40.805956",
           "40.808355",
           "40.810442",
           "40.812313",
           "40.812999"
      ],
      "Lon":[
           "29.430671",
           "29.432577",
           "29.434388",
           "29.435054",
           "29.434257",
           "29.43324",
           "29.431369",
           "29.431989",
           "29.43216",
           "29.43305"
      ],
      "StopId":[
           "60405",
           "60307",
           "60305",
           "60267",
           "60268",
           "60269",
           "60270",
           "60271",
           "60272",
           "60123"
      ],
      "StopName":[
           "BEYLİKBAĞI OTOBÜSLERİ",
           "BÜLBÜL",
           "DEKORASYON",
           "HÜRRİYET",
           "CHRYSLER İ.Ö.O.",
           "BAHAR",
           "DOĞAN",
           "CEMAL GÜRSEL",
           "ŞEHİT ERDEM DEMİR",
           "TUNA PARKI"
      ]
 },
 "timeInfo":{
      "DepartureTime":{
      },
      "WheelChairId":{
      }
 },
 "pointsInfo":{
      "Lat":[
           "40.8",
           "40.80032",
           "40.80066",
           "40.80106",
           "40.801014",
           "40.80099",
           "40.801434",
           "40.801594",
           "40.801685",
           "40.802128"
       ],
      "Lon":[
           "29.430689",
           "29.431099",
           "29.431581",
           "29.432386",
           "29.432484",
           "29.432804",
           "29.434998",
           "29.435455",
           "29.435163",
           "29.43496"
      ],
      "SeqNo":[
           "1",
           "2",
           "3",
           "4",
           "5",
           "6",
           "7",     
           "8",
           "9",
           "10"
      ]
 },
 "busInfo":{
      "Lat":{
      },
      "Lon":{
      },
      "Bus_id":{
      }
 },
 "refreshCount":0
 }
```

I'd like to read `SeqNo`, `Lat`, `Lon`, `StopId`, `StopName`, that have to same counts for all that sections.

Is there way to read them at the same time as one object?

Thanks for the advices.

EDIT: I solved the problem with these 3 lines codes :)

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("busStopInfo");
JSONArray seqNo = posts.getJSONArray("SeqNo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [You are not forced to provide each fields of the destination Object in your JSon](http://www.ggkf.com/json/dynamic-model-creation-for-json-parsing-using-gson-in-java) is what your looking for